# How to pass variables to represent a string in xpath - Selenium

Tags: python, string, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to use selenium webdriver to locate an element in html

```
size_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[text()= 'XL']")
```

The above works.

However, if I tried to represent `"XL"` with a string variable like below, it won't work.

```
size = "XL"

size_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[text()= f'{size}']")
```

similarly, the below don't work either:

```
size_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[text()= {}]".format(size)

size_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[text()= %s]"%size)
```

Comment: The `f` is in the wrong place.  It needs to be at the beginning of the outer string: `f"//span..."`

Answer (score 1):

> “F-strings provide a way to embed expressions inside string literals,
> using a minimal syntax. It should be noted that an f-string is really
> an expression evaluated at run time, not a constant value.

The below should work:

```
size = "XL"

size_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//span[text()= {size}]")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
size_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,f'//span[text()= {size}]')
```